# Tomar un código de barras y colocarlo en 2 array

Tags: c#, .net, código-de-barras

Me encuentro haciendo un punto de venta en **C#** para una [charcutería](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuter%C3%ADa) la cual usa un lector de código de barras, el código de barras que es generado por una balanza **LS21530EC** (homologada a Venezuela), ésta imprime un código de este tipo:

`[3][001][200][2]`

Donde:

- El primer dígito tiene que ver con la **tecla** del **PLU**.
- Los siguientes 3 dígitos con el **código** del **PLU** de la balanza.
- Los siguientes 3 tienen que ver con el **peso**.
- El último tienen relación con un *departamento* de esta balanza.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo obtener los primeros 3 que serian el código del ítem dentro del sistema y que coloque los siguientes 3 en el renglón de cantidad y luego dé el `<Enter>` necesario para que baje el ítem y seguir colocando productos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dividir una cadena en *partes*, puedes valerte de [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-gt/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx), así:

```
{
    string codigoBarras = ObtenerCodigoDeBalanza();
    string tecla = codigoBarras.Substring(0, 1);
    string plu = codigoBarras.Substring(1, 3);
    string peso = codigoBarras.Substring(4, 3); 
    string departamento = codigoBarras.Substring(7, 1); 
    Procesar(plu, peso);
}
```

Comment: me quedaria algo como esto???
`private async void CodigoBarrasTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {

}
{
    string codigoBarras = ObtenerCodigoDeBalanza();
    string tecla = codigoBarras.Substring(0, 1);
    string plu = codigoBarras.Substring(1, 3);
    string peso = codigoBarras.Substring(4, 3); 
    string departamento = codigoBarras.Substring(7, 1); 
    Procesar(plu, peso);
}
}`

Comment: Lo que te doy es código para que tu lo interpretes y lo adaptes a tu uso. ObtenerCodigoDeBalanza() y Procesar() probablemente no existan en tu clase, pero si estudias el código dado, con algo de suerte entenderás qué es lo que debes hacer para adaptarlo a tu clase.

Comment: perfecto muchisimas gracias

Comment: claro tendria que trabajar en ObtenerCodigoDeBalanza() y Procesar() e implementarlo, muchisimas gracias amigo, popr aca siempre me ayudan

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, podrías considerar [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), para que otros usuarios en el futuro puedan identificar fácilmente que te ha servido.

Comment: Perfecto amigo que este bien gracias